# How to call this refresh action as a continuous background job

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

This is part of an electron app, this action is called on pressing refresh button on UI. I want to make it autorefresh. How do I do it?

Components/counter.js:

```
export default class Counter extends Component<Props> {
  props: Props;

  render() {
    const {
      refresh,
      counter
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <button onClick={() => refresh()}>
        Refresh
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

actions/counter.js:

```
export function refresh() {
  // Do some local CRUD here.
  return {
    type: NO-OP
  };
}
```

Comment: what about dispatching action in `setTimeout` or `setInterval` ?

Comment: new to react/redux, code please.

Comment: Can I have the definition of `refresh` function?

Comment: you can assume this is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a function that continously calls `setTimeout`, and stops when the component is unmounted:

**Example**

```
class Counter extends Component {
  runRefresh = () => {
    this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
      this.props.refresh();
      this.runRefresh();
    }, 1000);
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.runRefresh();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearTimeout(this.timer);
  }

  render() {
    const { refresh, counter } = this.props;
    return <button onClick={() => refresh()}>Refresh</button>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you need to refresh on regular interval in your application.

So in `redux` action creators you can write:
Here `refreshInterval` is defined in action creator.

```
startRefresh(){
  refreshIntervalId = window.setInterval(() => {
    refresh();
  }, 3000);
}
```

OR if you are just returning action object from `refresh` function then you should use [redux-thunk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk)

```
startRefresh => dispatch => (){
  refreshIntervalId = window.setInterval(() => {
    dispatch(refresh());
  }, 3000);
}
```

You can call this `startRefresh` function in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method of your main app component OR from the component you wish.

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.props.startRefresh()
}
```

Also you should store the `id` of this interval and clear the interval on `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle method.

```
componentWillUnmount(){
    this.props.clearRefreshInterval()
}
```

`clearRefreshInterval` would simply be like:

```
clearRefreshInterval(){
    window.clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
}
```

Comment: can you give those codes too ie componentDidMount and componentWillUnmount